# PHP POCO style database access

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

With PHP I know how to access databases using mysql_query(), PDO->query() and pdo->prepare() followed by PDO->bindParam() and PDO->execute().

However in the past I have come across a method of database access where you have a class object which contains variable names which mirror the fields in a database and you change the field values to interact with the database.

I have only seen this done in C# however. The C# object is known as a POCO object and looks like a class with only variables in it.

Is it possible to do something similar in PHP PDO.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use PDO with `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` or `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`.

See documentation:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php

Example:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(...);
$stmt->execute();
while ($obj = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
  // $obj is a new object of class stdClass
  echo $obj->columnname
}
```

Example:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(...);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'MyClass');
while ($obj = $stmt->fetch()) {
  // $obj is a new object of class MyClass
  echo $obj->columnname
}
```

Comment: I have use PDO::FETCH_OBJ to read data

ie

$A = PDO->Prepare(.....)
$A->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'MyClass');

while ($row $A->fetch()){
$B = $row->fieldname 
} 

But is it possible to submit changes which have to be made to the database by submitting a class object

Comment: No, not unless you write that functionality yourself in the code for `MyClass`.

Comment: But you could use a more fully-features ORM like Doctrine or Zend Framework, but that's getting pretty far afield from your original question about POCO.

Comment: Yeah PDO is database access only
Zend is a full PHP framework